# Unable to solve error when using last element as pivot in quicksort

Tags: java, algorithm, quicksort

I have implemented QuickSort in Java. The Code for using first element as pivot works fine. I am trying to implement it using last element as pivot in similar way but am unable to find out why it is crashing.

`partitionFirst()` function uses the first element as pivot
`partitionLast()` function uses the last element as pivot

The code breaks at line 75 and line 77 which I have mentioned in the code. When using `partitionLast()`

If you will notice in `partitionLast()` I have returned pivot logic in a different way keeping in mind the case in which pivot will always be less than elements. For example. { 7 8 9 4 5 6 |3| } where 3 is partition

It will be helpful if somebody can point out error in the code. Also feel free to suggest Optimization if any.

```
public class QuickSort {
public void swap(int[] arr, int i, int j)
{
    if(i!=j)
    {
        int temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[j];
        arr[j] = temp;
    }
}

public int partitionFirst(int arr[], int start,int end)
{
    int j = start + 1;
    int pivot = arr[start]; 
    for(int i=start+1;i<end;i++)
    {
        if(pivot > arr[i])
        {
            swap(arr,i,j);
            j++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr,start,j-1);
    return (j-1);
}

public int partitionLast(int arr[], int start,int end)
{
    int j = start;
    int pivot = arr[(end - 1)]; 
    for(int i=start;i < end - 1  ;i++)
    {
        if(pivot > arr[i])
        {
            swap(arr,i,j);
            j++;
        }
    }
    if((j - 1) < 0)
    {
        swap(arr,end-1 ,j);
        return j;
    }
    else
    {
        swap(arr,end-1 ,(j-1));
        return (j-1);
    }
}

public void QuickSort(int arr[], int start,int end)
{
    if(end > start)
    {

        int p = partitionLast(arr, start, end); //75 line
        QuickSort(arr,start, p);
        QuickSort(arr,p+1,end); //77 line
    }
    return;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    int[] brr = {1,6,8,2,3,4};
    QuickSort ob1 = new QuickSort();
    ob1.QuickSort(brr,0,brr.length);
}
```

}

/* Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError at QuickSort.QuickSort(QuickSort.java:75) at QuickSort.QuickSort(QuickSort.java:77) at QuickSort.QuickSort(QuickSort.java:77) ....... */

Comment: Please act on [ask] &  [mcve]. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: Have specified in Question as well

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to swapping the correct element with the pivot:

```
public int partitionLast(int arr[], int start,int end)
{
    int j = start;
    int pivot = arr[(end - 1)];
    for(int i=start;i < end - 1  ;i++)
    {
        if(pivot > arr[i])
        {
            swap(arr,i,j);
            j++;
        }
    }
    swap(arr,end-1,j);
    return (j);
}
```

Comment: My Logic for partitionFirst() function was in case the "if statement" turns out to be true in final iteration, an excess increment of j will be there. Why is it not applicable in partitionLast() function

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. The if statement is identical in both implementations. Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: @akatira - PartitionFirst final swap and return should use j-1, swapping the pivot at arr[start] with a value <= pivot. ParitionLast final swap and return should use j, swapping the pivot at arr[end-1] with a value >= pivot.